# Проверка орфографии слова из слов в базе

Tags: .net, vb.net, проверка-орфографии

Как написать программу для проверки "орфографии слова" из слов, которые записаны в базе, в VB.net 2008, не предлагать открытие Word-а в фоновом режиме.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать любую библиотеку для .NET, например, [NHunspell](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/), которая поддерживает словари OpenOffice.

Алгоритм работы обычный: запрос к словарю, если слово неверное, - список возможных кандидатов.

Comment: Но как сделать так чтобы вывести список возможных кандидатов например если он ввёл слово "шлола" а не школа как узнать что он хотел написать школа?